# How to guarantee that messages in Kafka not lost if service crashed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Fist of all the configuration of the client in our service group is `enable.auto.commit = false` and `auto.offset.reset = earliest` to ensure that not processed messages are not committed.

Now I want to understand how can I guarantee that messages not lost if for example service crushed.
What I want to ensure is the following scenario:

1. Received message A with offset 1 - service starts to process the message (async)
2. Received message B with offset 2 - service starts to process the message (async)
3. Processing of message B finished and the offset 2 committed to Kafka.
4. Service restarts before finishing the processing of message A and committing offset 1.
5. Service starts again and processing messages from offset 1 as it was not committed yet.

If I understand right then when the service starts again it will receive messages starting from offset 3 and the message in offset 1 will be lost is it right?

If I right can I fix it with configuration or required some kind of management of committed offsets?

Answer (score 0):

For consumers, unless they produce back to kafka, kafka supports at best `at-least-once` semantic, which is your case, and you want to achieve `exactly-once` semantic as I understand.

Again if you don't use a processor logic Kafka to Kafka `(consume process produce from and to Kafka)` , you have two options to achieve exactly once:

- You can deal with duplicates, caused by the `at-least-once` delivery semantic, with idempotent consumers.
- If our destination system is not Kafka but has transactional support, you can solve this just like Kafka does in the Kafka to Kafka case with transctions, by atomically updating the destination and storing the offsets as part of a transaction.

Also worth mentioning that, depending on your use case, you may find a `connector` that already solves your problem.

These reads could help you understand better your problem and possible solutions:

- [Processing Guaruantees](https://medium.com/@andy.bryant/processing-guarantees-in-kafka-12dd2e30be0e)
- [Transactions in Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/)